Cat being looked after by neighbour for 1 month. No access to his home
I'm going to be away for one month.
My neighbour has kindly offered to care for my cat whilst I am gone.
He is an outdoor cat so we have fitted a Catflap on her front door.
My cat won't have access to my house whilst I am gone (property has been rented out on Air B&B and guest has said no to a resident cat.)
I'm worried this is going to be stressful for my cat as he won't be able to access his 'home.'
We have begun to take him to my neighbours for 4/5 hours a day - just to get familiar with the space.
From tomorrow I will start to serve all his meals from her house.
I have also brought various beds and toys of his to her home to make it smell more familiar, and have put a Feliway scent diffuser on.
I go away in 2 weeks.
Is there anything else I should / could be doing to make this transition easier for my boy?

Withdrew my answer since I noticed you said you plan to let the cat continue going outdoors. That's a serious complication; the cat may decide to try to find its way back home. I'm not comfortable advising under those conditions.
